# Can I privately use copyrighted materials as test data for public projects?

Tags: copyright

Some time ago I started to develop a 'Sudoku Solver' using Python. Of course, there are many Sudoku solvers already available as open source projects, but I did not want to use any of those, because I was looking for a  '***just for fun***' project. Therefore, I start the development of a 'Sudoku Solver', just to see how it goes.
I needed some data to test my program, therefore I searched the web, and I found plenty of Sudoku games, publicly available, free to solve, but from the copyright point of view '**All Rights Reserved**'. I also used some free Sudoku games available on Android.
The development went pretty well, and I successfully found solutions for both classic Sudoku and for a plethora of Sudoku variants, for which I could not found existing open source solvers available. Now I am considering to share the code for the Sudoku solvers as open source software, most likely using a permissive license like MIT, which means the code can be used for commercial purposes.  The Sudoku games (All Rights Reserved) I used during development as test data, from a multitude of public sources and authors, will not be incorporated into the public project.

In doing so, am I infringing the copyright of Sudoku authors somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not distributing the Sudoku games that you used as test data, then you are not infringing on the copyrights of their authors.

Assuming you have written a generic Sudoku solver, then your solver is not a derived work of the games you used to test it. That means that your solver cannot infringe upon the copyrights of those game's authors.

Another way of infringing copyrights is distributing a work without being authorized to do so and that could be the case if you include those "All Rights Reserved" games in your distribution.